# Remove non-Arabic words in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove non Arabic words in r
and i tried this code but it is removed everything

```
> L<-"you المجدo to yes"
> gsub("[^\\p{InArabic}.,]+","",L)
[1] ""
```

Comment: You likely need to add `perl = TRUE` in order for R to compile the regex in PCRE mode. Also I'm not sure that `{InArabic}` is supported - though `{Arabic}` does seem to be ex. `gsub("[^\\p{Arabic}.,]+", "", L, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `perl = TRUE` in order for R to compile the regex in PCRE mode.

Also I'm not sure that `{InArabic}` is a supported character class - though `{Arabic}` does seem to be, at least in my version of R (*R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"*):

```
> L<-"you المجدo to yes"
> 
> gsub("[^\\p{Arabic}.,]+", "", L, perl = TRUE)
[1] "المجد"
```